How do I rewrite this TRY/CATCH so that this specific error is caught?
I ran this code in SSMS and it ran fine. I then had Microsoft Access call a stored procedure that runs the same code below and it errored out. It looks like the problem is that Access was using a user called 'ATS_User' to execute its stored procedures while in SSMS it ran under a different user that has the appropriate permission. Is there a way to rewrite this so that the given error can be caught?

Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

begin try

    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @Profile_Name = 'SQL_Email'
        , @Recipients = @CurrentEmail
        , @Subject = @Subject
        , @Body = @Body
        , @File_Attachments = @FilePath

end try
begin catch
    --Code is not landing here when run by a user without EXECUTE permission

    /*
    ...handle error...
    */
    return

end catch


There are many errors that try/catch won't catch see try/catch - this appears to be one of them.

What seems to be the problem? e.g. db<>fiddle

I agree with @AlwaysLearning, I tested it and the catch works. How exactly do you "...handle error..."  ?

@DaleK There are many comments that are made with low effort - this appears to be one of them.

@AlwaysLearning this code is inside a stored procedure when called through MS Access, which is when the problem occurs.

@AlwaysLearning if I wrap your code in a SP, it doesn't give the error anymore: https://dbfiddle.uk/Xn_Ljkaj

@TheMortiestMorty that's because you're trying to execute the stored proc in the same batch that you create it, see: db<>fiddle.

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @Profile_Name = 'SQL_Email',
        @Recipients = @CurrentEmail,
        @Subject = @Subject,
        @Body = @Body,
        @File_Attachments = @FilePath;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Handle the error here
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 229
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Permission denied: The user does not have the necessary permissions to execute this procedure.';
        -- Additional handling for permission error
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END
    RETURN;
END CATCH;


This didn't work. The error still silently went uncaught
